# Add setter method to a scala class

Tags: scala, class, setter

I'm reading a book "Scala in action" to learn scala. On page 59, the author provide following code. But when I run it, it doesn't compile.

```
class Person(var firstName:String, var lastName:String, private var _age:Int) {
  def age = _age
  def age_ = (newAge: Int) = _age = newAge //Error
}
```

It reports:

`<console>:3: ';' expected but '=' found.
def age_ = (newAge: Int) = _age = newAge}`

This book use scala 2.10. I'm using scala 2.11.

Does scala change the usage of setter method in 2.11?

Comment: You have an extra space between `age_` and `=` - it needs to be one "word": `age_=`

Comment: If you remove the space as @Shadowlands notes, you can set the age with `bob.age_=(43)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the context of `def age_ = (newAge: Int) = _age = newAge` or what the author is trying to demonstrate with that line. Parameters of the constructor are public by default so removing `private` allows you to use the setter for free.

```
scala> class Person(var firstName:String, var lastName:String, var _age:Int) {}
defined class Person

scala> val bob = new Person("Bob", "Smith", 42)
bob: Person = Person@290d210d

scala> bob._age = 43
bob._age: Int = 43

scala> bob._age
res9: Int = 43
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the only problem is the missprint ' ' ('space') simbol of the errored line between 'underscore' and 'equals'.
The right code is:

```
  def age_= (newAge: Int) = _age = newAge //NO Error
```

Lets remove syntax sugar (plus abit classic formatting) and we'll have more clear method that is really the setter for "variable" `age` "backed" to `private var _age`

```
  def age_=(newAge: Int): Unit = {
    _age = newAge
  }
```

Think about such variables as if it is virtual-like: this setter with previously defined getter but possibly with no storage at all. For instance, both uses HTTP requests (GET & PUT) to store/retrieve the value).

So, the first '=' is really the part of the method name `age_=` that is the syntax Scala uses to define setter for `age`.